# Create a shortcut for a string that goes through a program

Tags: linux, bash, shortcut, xclip

I have to, a lot of times, get things onto the clipboard from the terminal. I do it like this:

```
echo "something"|xclip -selection clipboard
```

Doing this every time is way too lame, and I want to make a shortcut. How do I do it?

Comment: Do you mean a real shortcut (that is, instead of pressing enter you press ctrl+... and then the current command line is executed and its output written to the clipboard)?

Comment: Can you clarify your question by saying whether you'd like a shorter version of `xclip -selection clipboard` or just an improved way to copy in the terminal?

Comment: basically. I want to make a script, named `cpstring`. If I go and type `cpstring "anything"`, `"anything"` gets copied

Comment: @prokopvictor What's stopping you? Is your question "How do I access command line parameters in a shell script?"

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function:

```
clip() {
    echo "$@" | xclip -selection clipboard   
}
```

add it to your initialization script (~/.bashrc), then use it:

```
clip something
clip "one two"
```

Comment: I think `echo "$@"` would be a bit better. That way you can use `clip` just like `echo`. For instance, you could write `clip a b` instead of `clip "a b"`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use alias.
Add below line to `~/.bash_aliases`.

```
alias my_alias_name="xclip -selection clipboard"
```

Then you go like this:

```
echo "something" | my_alias_name
```

You have to come up with good name for that on your own.

---

Answering your comment:

> ...the little script i could make is named cpstring and I go cpstring
>   "anything". Is there a way to do this with bash scripting?

Create **cpstring** file, put it somewhere visible by your $PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$@" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Remember to add exe rights to that file: `chmod +x cpstring`

Comment: I will probably do this, but, let's say, the little script i could make is named `cpstring` and I go `cpstring "anything"`. Is there a way to do this with bash scripting?